# Vuejs v-show is not working as expected

Tags: vue.js

I have a form to add new items to my array, but would like to hide the form until the user is ready to add an item.  The form is hidden and I have a `@click` function attached to an icon to toggle the form to show, which is also working. But, as soon as the form is toggle to show, it hides automatically within a few seconds.

**@click icon**

```
<li class="m-portlet__nav-item">
  <a href="" class="m-portlet__nav-link m-portlet__nav-link--icon" @click="isSection ^= true">
    <i class="flaticon-add"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

**form**

```
<div class="row" v-show="isSection">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #fcfcfc; padding: 1em">
      <h5>Add New Section</h5>
      <hr>
      <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewSection">
        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
          <input v-model="sections.name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control m-input" style="margin-bottom: .5rem"/>
          <textarea v-model="sections.description" placeholder="Description" class="form-control m-input" style="margin-bottom: .5rem"/></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Section</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
new Vue({
    el: "#main",
    data: {
        isSection: false,
        ...
```

**addNewSection**

```
addNewSection() {
    this.sections.push(
        {
            name: this.sections.name,
            description: this.sections.description,
            items: []
        }
    );
    this.sections.name = "";
    this.sections.description = "";
},
```

Comment: Can you show some of the `addNewSection`?  Is it relevant?

Comment: @zero298 It shouldn't be relevant, but I added it to the original question.

Comment: Any reason why you're using "isSection ^= true" on your @click? (instead of "isSection = true" or "isSection = !isSection" for toggle)

Also, have you tried changing v-show to v-if?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By setting `href=""` here:

```
<a href="" class="m-portlet__nav-link m-portlet__nav-link--icon" @click="isSection ^= true">
```

you are triggering a re-load of your page when you click the link.

Try `href="#"`.

```
<a href="#" class="m-portlet__nav-link m-portlet__nav-link--icon" @click="isSection ^= true">
```

I expect you also just want to negate `isSection` as mentioned in the comment above even though what you wrote does serve the same purpose; it's not a commonly used syntax.

```
<a href="#" class="m-portlet__nav-link m-portlet__nav-link--icon" @click="isSection = !isSection">
```

Comment: In all honesty, I think it should be a `<button>` for accessibility purposes.

Comment: @zero298 I wouldn't disagree with that.

Comment: Yes, i think a button is a better approach to make it work

Comment: if the project uses **Vue Router** and the mode is **hashmode**, it is not a good idea to use `href="any"`. uses `style="cursor: pointer"` if you only need the pointer same as `<a href="any">`